# Can continuous dataset have negative values?

Tags: distribution, mathematics

As in the description, I want to choose continuos dataset with temperatures and the minimun value is -40 and maximum is 51. Is that OK? Can we have negative values in continuous distribution?

Comment: yes, why do you think this is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Why would a negative temperature make no sense? Unless the temperature is measured in Kelvin...

You should know what each feature describes, and based on that, make sure the data makes sense. As of the dataset itself, with no context, it is indeed possible for any numerical feature to take negative numbers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, its in celcius. Thanks!

Comment: Hm @89f2a1c on the other hand when I want to make a distribution in R it says "values must be positive to fit an exponential  distribution" and here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/FAQ.html it is not recommended to have such datasets

Comment: Well, that's a whole other story. The question would then be 'can an exponential distribution contain negative values'? No, it definitely can't.